# Transform permutation into another permutation with minimum swaps and/or moves

Tags: permutations, permutation-cycles

I have a problem that is a combination of two other asked questions:

- [Transform permutation into another permutation with minimum swaps](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1897308/transform-permutation-into-another-permutation-with-minimum-swaps)
- [Minimum number of moves (not swaps) to transform one permutation into another](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1860383/minimum-number-of-moves-not-swaps-to-transform-one-permutation-into-another)

That is, given two permutations `x` and `y`, what is the minimum sequence of swap and/or move operations to transform `x` to `y`?

**Definitions:**

- swap `s(i, j)`: Swaps the `i`-th with the `j`-th element of the permutation.

  Note: this is equivalent to `s(j, i)`.
- move `m(i ,j)`: Removes the `i`-th element and inserts it to the `j`-th position. The positions of all elements between `i` and `j` are:

  - decremented by one position ("shifted to the left") if `i < j`
  - incremented by one position ("shifted to the right") if `i > j`

  Note: this is *not* equivalent to `m(j, i)`.
- Positions are zero-based.

**Example**

- `x: AFDEBGC`
- `y: ABCDEFG`
- Using only swaps, 5 operations would be needed, for example:

  ```
  AFDEBGC => s(1,4) ==
  ABDEFGC => s(4,3) ==
  ABDFEGC => s(3,2) ==
  ABFDEGC => s(2,6) ==
  ABCDEGF => s(6,5) ==
  ABCDEFG
  ```
- Using only moves, 3 operations would be needed, for example:

  ```
  AFDEBGC => m(4,1) ==
  ABFDEGC => m(6,2) ==
  ABCFDEG => m(3,5) ==
  ABCDEFG
  ```
- Using both swaps and moves, only 2 operations would be needed, for example:

  ```
  AFDEBGC => s(1,4) ==
  ABDEFGC => m(6,2) ==
  ABCDEFG
  ```

Comment: Note that the first link is to a question about using only adjacent swaps, but you are allowing all swaps. Swaps are also called transpositions, and there are many posts about writing permutations as a product of transpositions, e.g. [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/616889/362967) which shows the minimum is $n-s$ where $s$ is the number of disjoint cycles in the permutation. For moves-only I don't know what the optimum is in general, but the worst case is $n-1$ for the reversed list. No idea about combining moves and swaps.